# Count and result from Inner Join

Tags: sql, firebird

I have this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT
  ART.LFDNR,
  ARTSTLST.ARTIKELLFDNR,
  Count(*) AS counts
FROM
  ARTIKEL ART
  INNER JOIN ARTSTLST ON ARTSTLST.OARTIKELLFDNR = ART.LFDNR
WHERE
  ART.SUCHARTIKELNR = '22424'
GROUP BY
  ART.LFDNR,
  ARTSTLST.ARTIKELLFDNR            )
```

which results in my case in

```
3
```

But I want to show also the result of the inner query

```
SELECT
  ART.LFDNR,
  ARTSTLST.ARTIKELLFDNR,
  Count(*) AS counts
FROM
  ARTIKEL ART
  INNER JOIN ARTSTLST ON ARTSTLST.OARTIKELLFDNR = ART.LFDNR
WHERE
  ART.SUCHARTIKELNR = '22424'
GROUP BY
  ART.LFDNR,
  ARTSTLST.ARTIKELLFDNR
```

so the result would look like this

```
12345        34567        3
```

Which is the result of the selct plus the Count() result.

Comment: Please elaborate, share how result should look.

Comment: Take the time to describe what your data looks like and what results you want.  If you won't even make the effort to *ask* the question, why should anyone take the effort to *answer* it?

Comment: I changed the whole question, I thought it was very clear.

Comment: It wasn't and to me it still isn't. If the count is 3, it means the subselect has 3 rows. How come then that you want the final output as a single row? How would you want to get it from a 3-row input?

Answer (score 1):

This would be easy using Windowed Aggregate Function:

```
SELECT
  ART.LFDNR,
  ARTSTLST.ARTIKELLFDNR,
  Count(*) AS counts,
  SUM(Count(*)) OVER () -- Group sum
FROM
  ARTIKEL ART
  INNER JOIN ARTSTLST ON ARTSTLST.OARTIKELLFDNR = ART.LFDNR
WHERE
  ART.SUCHARTIKELNR = '22424'
GROUP BY
  ART.LFDNR,
  ARTSTLST.ARTIKELLFDNR
```

But AFAIK only Firebird 3 (currently in beta) supports those functions, so you need a more complicated query utilizing a Common Table Expression:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( 
    SELECT
      ART.LFDNR,
      ARTSTLST.ARTIKELLFDNR,
      Count(*) AS counts
    FROM
      ARTIKEL ART
      INNER JOIN ARTSTLST ON ARTSTLST.OARTIKELLFDNR = ART.LFDNR
    WHERE
      ART.SUCHARTIKELNR = '22424'
    GROUP BY
      ART.LFDNR,
      ARTSTLST.ARTIKELLFDNR  
 ) 
SELECT cte.*, (SELECT SUM(counts) FROM cte)
FROM cte
```

Comment: Wow, I actually thought its very easy and just my lack of knowledge, but good that I asked, this would have been unsolveable for me. Thanx!